# Создание новой кнопки Button

Tags: c#, winforms

Как создать кнопку Button, при нажатии на которую форма будет создавать новые экземпляры?

Comment: Экземпляры чего?

Comment: должны при щелчке на кнопку выходить пустые Button кнопки в приложении

Comment: @Павел если прямо в лоб, то можно создать их заранее невидимыми, а при нажатии сделать видимыми))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот так, например:

```
Button b1 = new Button();
b1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y); 
b1.Size = new Size(125, 32);
b1.TabIndex = 0;
b1.Text = "TEXT";
b1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
Form1.Controls.Add(b1);
```